# Npm install has exited with non zero status. Some dependencies are not installed. Check npm command output

Tags: node.js, npm, vaadin, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to Vaadin and WSL. Therefore, I am stuck at a point in my WSL Ubuntu environment where I can not run my maven project. This same project runs without any issues from my windows. Here is a screenshot of the errors.

[Error while running the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjZ6u.png)

Even npm install fails and shows this error on my Intellij IDE.
[NPM install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in06z.png)

Can Somebody please help to identify the reason behind these and suggest a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Vaadin should automatically install Node if a suitable version is not present. Maybe that’s failing on Ubuntu for some reason, in which case installing Node manually could help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)